# How can I start a new browser instance with Selenium RC after tearDown?

Tags: selenium, configuration, selenium-rc, testng

My problem is that I want to run 2 suites of tests. When the second suit of test starts i get the Error: 
`Server Exception: sessionId should not be null; has this session been started yet?`

My Testng.xml file looks like this:

```
<suite name="Suite" parallel="false">
    <suite-files>
        <suite-file path="testng1.xml"/>
        <suite-file path="testng2.xml"/>
    </suite-files>
</suite>
```

I should mention that every class from testng1 and testng2 files have a `@BeforeSuite` annotation that invokes setUp method that looks like this:

```
public void setUp() {
    String url = mySelSetter.url;
    String browser = mySelSetter.browser;
    if (selenium == null) {
        selenium = new DefaultSelenium("localhost", 4445, browser, url);
        selenium.start();
        selenium.open(url);
        System.out.println("A browser instance opens.");
    } else {
        System.out.println("A browser instance is already open.");
    }
}
```

Comment: My Selenium RC knowledge is long gone, but would it work if you removed the `(selenium == null)` check? Obviously, the check could pass even when there's no browser opened. Or, the other way around - in your `teadDown()` method, after `selenium.stop()` place `selenium = null;` to signal that the browser has been closed.

Comment: Every time someone asks a basic question about Selenium RC, I only recommend to update to [WebDriver](http://code.google.com/p/selenium/wiki/GettingStarted)!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to create a selenium instance only once. After that you have to `start()` and `stop()` the selenium before and after your test steps.
Check below.

```
public void setUp() {
 String url = mySelSetter.url;
 String browser = mySelSetter.browser;
 if (selenium == null) 
 {
     selenium = new DefaultSelenium("localhost", 4445, browser, url);

 } else {
     System.out.println("A browser instance is already open.");
 }
 selenium.start();
 selenium.open(url);
 System.out.println("A browser instance opens.");
}
```

I strongly recommend that you to move to WebDriver. RC is now a lost memory.